# OpticSlim 2610 Plus supported?

Tags: sane

I need a scanner on my linux (Debian bullseye).
Sane is the software stack, handling scanners.

The device is visible to USB:

```
> lsusb  
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 07b3:1806 Plustek, Inc. USB2.0 Scanner(7M4)
```

But if I issue

```
> sudo scanimage -L  
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

I tried to specify the device in `/etc/sane.d/plustek.conf`:

```
> [usb] 0x07b3 0x1806  
device auto
```

But this does not seem to help matters.

So, here the question: Am I missing something or is this product simply not supported?

Comment: Is that model in the list of supported devices on http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-PLUSTEK ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, but there are devices supported which use the same ASIC. So I thought, someone might know, how to get it working anyway.

Comment: Ah then the communication platforms of the sane project are most likely a more promising place to ask. Same ASIC might or might not make it easy.